# Files With A Tag in ObsidianMD

Tags: javascript, typescript, obsidian

I'm trying to write a plugin that fetches the list of files containing a particular tag (like "#condition") in ObsidianMD for some downstream purposes. The built-in `global-search` can do this already, and it seems like the `metadataCache` has some information about tags.

Further, the API appears to be able to `getAllTags`: https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-api/blob/master/obsidian.d.ts#L1291, but I don't see any method that takes a tag and spits out a list of related files.

Does anyone know anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`app.vault.getMarkdownFiles()`](https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-api/blob/036708710c4a4b652d8166c5929d5ba1ffb7fb91/obsidian.d.ts#L3428) to get all markdown files in the current vault, then use [`getAllTags()`](https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-api/blob/036708710c4a4b652d8166c5929d5ba1ffb7fb91/obsidian.d.ts#L1338) on each file to filter those files which contain the tag. Example:

```
const tag = "#obsidian";
const cache = this.app.metadataCache;
const files = this.app.vault.getMarkdownFiles();
const files_with_tag = [] as TFile [];
files.forEach( (file) => {
    const file_cache = cache.getFileCache(file);
    const tags = getAllTags(file_cache);
    if (tags.includes(tag)) {
        files_with_tag.push(file);
    }
});
console.log(files_with_tag);
```